# Shift 32 bit Numbers on a 16 bit Datapath

Tags: cpu-architecture, 32-bit, riscv, 16-bit, riscv32

### How to Shift 32 Bit Numbers on a 16 Bit Datapath

This is a computer architecture question.

---

My datapath is only 16 bit wide, meaning my ALU can only process 16 bit operands at a time.
My registers are 32 bits wide and are addressable in lower and upper 16 bit portions.

Every time I read the lower half of a register I also read an extra bit telling me weather the upper half contains any 1s at all (ref 1).

---

So far I implemented the shift left logical. (**sll rd, rs1, rs2**)

- Read the lower half of the rs1 register, and shift it by the amount specified in the lower rs2 register
- The bits that I shifted out of these 16 bits, are being stored in a temporary 16 bit register inside the alu
- The shifted value will be written back to the lower rd register and the status bit is set (see ref 1)

Now if there is no data written in the higher rs1 register (see ref 1) and the bits that are in the temp alu register are all 0, then my shift operation is done.

Otherwise a second cycle for the upper half is needed

- Read the high rs1 register and shift it by the amount stored in the lower rs2 register
- But now fill the rs1 with the values stored in the alu temp register (not with 0 as in the first cycle)
- Bits shifted out of the 16bit space will be dropped
- The result is written back to the higher rd register, and the rd status bit is set (see ref 1)

---

Example 1: Lets say rs1 is 0x00001234 and rs2 is 0x00000002 (Perform a left shift by 2)

- First I read the lower 16bits of rs1 and rs2, presenting 0x1234 and 0x0002. But by reading that I do also get the status bits of both registers, in this case being 0 for rs1 and 0 for rs2 since the upper 16 bits of both registers are all 0. With the data given I can perform a left shift by 2. Resulting in 0x48D0. Since no 1s were shifted out of the sll I can store the result in lower rd and set its status bit to 0. (This is all done in one cycle)

Example 2: Lets say rs1 is 0x0000D234 and rs2 is 0x00000005 (Perform a left shift by 5)

- First I read the lower 16bits of rs1 and rs2, presenting 0xD234 and 0x0005. But by reading that I do also get the status bits of both registers, in this case being 0 for rs1 and 0 for rs2 since the upper 16 bits of both registers are all 0. With the data given I can perform a left shift by 5. Resulting in 0x4680. But now I shifted 11010 (0x1A) out of the 16 bit space. This value is stored in the Alu temp register and since it contains 1s I have to perform another cycle.
- In the second cycle I read the upper rs1 and lower rs2, presenting 0x0000 and 0x0005. I perform another shift left by 5, but now the Alu temp register is used to fill up the shifted values. 0x0000 -> 0x00__ -> 0x001A. This result is then written back to the upper rd. Therefore finishing my 32 bit sll in two 16 bit cycles.

Example 3: Lets say rs1 is 0x01231234 and rs2 is 0x00000002 (Perform a left shift by 2)

- First I read the lower 16bits of rs1 and rs2, presenting 0x1234 and 0x0002. But by reading that I do also get the status bits of both registers, in this case being 1 for rs1 and 0 for rs2 since the upper 16 bits of rs1 are non-zero. Since the status bit of rs1 was non-zero I have to preform a second cycle even if no 1s are shifted out of the lower 16 bits (See Example 2). From now on it follows Example 2, by writing back to rd and preforming a second cycle for the upper bits.

I hope these examples gave a better insight.

---

---

Now I want to **implement a right shift operation** (arithmetical and logical). But how to do that **in at most 2 cycles** and if I have to **read the lower rs1 register first (including the status bit)?**

---

Thanks for reading; this is my first question here, so please don't go to harsh on me :D

Comment: The description of the the logical left shift operation is not clear. So you can read the lower half of a register, shift it, check the status bit, write the shifted value in the destination register all in a single cycle? The bit at position 15 should be shifted into position 16. When is this done? Why do you need to fill the temp register with zeroes? Why do you need to "fill the rs1 with the values stored in the alu temp register"?

Comment: Yes, just like a normal 16 bit Operation; only that I do not read 16 bits from the register, Im reading 17 bit... were 16 bits are the operands and the last one is just a single bit describing weather the upper 16 bits are empty... so that I do not have to perform a read operation on the upper 16 bit if not necessary.

Comment: I added examples to my original question to clarify

Comment: I see. It seems to me that you can basically merge the value in the temporary ALU register with another given value. Also it looks like if the upper 16 bits of a register are zero (like in Example 1), you don't need to explicitly set them to zero. Just by setting the status bit to zero, the register perhaps by design sets all of these bits to zero. This is important because the current upper 16-bit value in the dest register may not be zero. You can't expect us to know such details without describing them precisely. A more precise description of the datapath is required.

Comment: Come on, please don't flame me; its my first ever interaction on stackoverflow. 
In fact you don't have to set the upper 16 bits to 0, since the next time they are accessed, they are not actually read. Since we already know the status bit, just 16 "0" are hard wired via a mux to the alu, saving the reg file read.

But this is not connected at all to my question so I did not mention it

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the higher part.
The first cycle you will read the high part. Do the right shift, the shifted out bits will be present in the high part of the tmp register and the result of the shift will be written back.
The second cycle , you read the low part , you do a shift and an or with the result present in the tmp register. then the result of this part will be written back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D
But this way every shift right would take 2 cycles. 
If the value to be shifted is only present in the lower 16 bits, there is no need to shift the upper part. And I can only determine that the upper part is empty by readying the status bit that is added to the lower 16 bits

Comment: If you start with the lower part , you will need one cylce if the upper part is equal to 0 . However you will need 3 cycles if it is different from 0 since you will need to shift the low part, shift the high part , or the tmp and the low part . Since you need the shift to be done in at most 2 cycles it is not acceptable.

Comment: Absolutely right ... but what I was wondering is if it is even possible to do in 2 cycles given these criteria

Comment: @Sun. Left shift is like `add` in that "carry" (or at least data dependency) propagates from right to left.  Right shift is special because it's the other way around.  Unless you can check the zero-upper flag in the *first* cycle and choose whether to do high then low, or only low in that same cycle, you're stuck with right shifts *always* taking 2 cycles.  Unless you have a 32-bit input / 16-bit output barrel shifter (useful for double-precision / shift one register into another), in which case you can just directly produce the low half output from both halves of the input and skip the high.

Comment: ok, thanks :D
That was also my standpoint on the problem... Either 3 cycles with the hardware available if any data is in the upper 16 bits or 2 cycles if the status bit is read independently of the lower 16 bits